# Generic class variable of a certain type

Tags: c++, class, generics, types, where-clause

In C# I can define this:

```
public interface BaseObject
{
    int GetValue();
}

public class Test<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    T BaseObject;
}
```

which means I know that I can alwaysa call BaseObject.GetValue() / BaseObject->GetValue(); because I know that the baseobject has this method.

Is there a similiar way to do this in C++? So that I can define an interface that multiple classes can inherit and a class that can take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

Templates, which are even more powerful than C# generics (not to say they are necessarily *better*, just different).

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
public:
    int whatever() 
    { 
        return obj.GetValue();
    }
private:
    T obj;
};
```

A separate class is created for each template argument you use.  If you provide a template type which would result in an error you will know at compile time.

Comment: But I need to restrict T to be of a certain type. So it has to be an object that inherits from another object.

Comment: @Deukalion: Well then you can use C#.  C++ is a different language with different semantics.  I don't think you *need* to do what you say, it's just your perception as you are more experienced with how things are done in C# and inexperienced in C++.  You still get compile time checking that your template argument supports the required interface, but not at a type level.

Comment: I asked if there is a similiar way to produce the same results instead of having to reproduce multiple classes. For example, if I want T to be a base class with methods that the class holding the object will use but another object can extend this object for it's purposes which means that the object only needs to know that it's an object inherited from BaseClass.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't know that it wasn't possible and perhaps shouldn't have to be, just if there is an easy way to do it.

Comment: "This is essentially text replacement."  Nothing could be further from the truth.  Repeat 10,000 times, C++ templates are NOT C/C++ macros.  Text replacement (macros) can't do specialization, participate in overload resolution, and macro metaprogramming is very very clunky.

Comment: @BenVoigt to be fair, template metaprogramming can also be very very clunky ;)

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's fair, I was being overly simplistic

Comment: @NikBougalis: Not to the same degree as macros.  And the problem spaces leading to clunky templates tend to be much harder than the ones leading to clunky macros.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about *C++ concepts*, a way to specify requirements for template parameters.  They were proposed during the work on C++11, but proved complicated enough that they weren't done in time.  But they've just been delayed, not forgotten.

In the meantime, duck typing remains very powerful, and it will catch when you pass a template parameter that doesn't have the required interface.  It just won't report the problem as neatly.

As a workaround, a simple way to check the constraint you showed takes advantage of the fact that pointer conversions are implicit only when upcasting:

```
public class Test<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    static T* enforcement_helper = 0;
    static BaseClass* enforce_inheritance_constraint = enforcement_helper;

};
```

Depending on how new your compiler is, you may need to put those lines inside a special member function (destructor is good, because it's almost always processed).

But you should only check constraints in order to improve error messages (by causing the failure in a clearly commented section of code).  C++ templates are duck typed, and they will work with any template parameters that provide the required operations.  No formal "interface" is required.